# Why my display is different than react-bootstrap example?

Tags: reactjs

I got this example from https://codesandbox.io/s/github/react-bootstrap/code-sandbox-examples/tree/master/basic. Referring to below image:

https://ibb.co/rZPn6L5

I copied whole code App.js and App.css, did a npm start. Below is from my web browser

https://ibb.co/LrP4NR2

Anything I missed ? My display is different that the one showed in codesandbox.

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example code snippet(s). A summary of what you're trying to do, what isn't working, and detailed information for any errors or warnings, and what your expected result should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also copy the imported minified bootstrap CSS file that was placed in `index.js`

```
// Importing the Bootstrap CSS
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Comment: After I added this css, able to see the same display. Big thank.

Comment: It's easy to miss in a demo sandbox, especially since they import it in a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

You likely forgot to copy over the dependencies from `package.json` and install them.

When you open the `package.json` in CodeSandbox, you will see this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
```

Do you have the `bootstrap` and `react-bootstrap` dependencies installed locally? If not, add this to your `package.json`:

```
"bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
"react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
```

I almost forgot; if you open the `index.js` in CodeSandbox, you will see the following two lines:

```
// Importing the Bootstrap CSS
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

You also need to copy over that code and put it in your local `index.js`.

Then run `npm install` or `yarn` (depending on which package manager you're using) and it should work.

By the way, looking at the URL I could tell that the code is coming from a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/code-sandbox-examples). You can just clone that repository with Git and and then run the examples locally. That's far better than copying and pasting code from CodeSandbox.

Comment: By cloning the example also helped.